# Is there a way to set a pallet for colours in an SVG image and change them at runtime for one gameobject?

Tags: unity, sprites, svg, vector-art

in the latest beta build for unity they introduced the ability to import svg files. What I'd like to know is if there is a way to identify all svg shapes by colour, and then change those colours, as if you were changing a class in CSS.

I suspect that you can go into an svg file, find where the text for colour is found and then change it, but I'm worried it'll change it for any object that use that svg file instead of changing it by gameobject.

The thing I'd like to do here is have customizable characters in a fighting game, where you can go into the menu and change their colours on a slider. so if I can identify like 3 colours in an svg and list them, and then edit those values in runtime or load, I'll have what I need